# Deployment of Node native modules to Azure WebSites

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, node-modules, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy the following sample node application to an Azure website:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

    try {

        var canvasModule = require('canvas'), 
            canvas = new canvasModule(200, 200), 
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.rotate(0.5);

        ctx.font = '30px Impact';
        var message = "Hello World";
        ctx.fillText(message, 40, 40);

        ctx.strokeRect(30, 5, 160, 50);

        res.end('<html><img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" /></html>');

    } catch (e) {
        res.end('Error: ' + e);
    }

}).listen(port);
```

The tricky part is that I'm using a node module called "[canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)" that needs to be compiled at install time using node-gyp.

According to [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/) Microsoft page native modules are not supported on Azure Web-sites and the compiled version of the module should be copied to Azure for the app to work properly:

> **Native Modules**
>
> While most modules are simply plain-text JavaScript files, some
>   modules are platform-specific binary images. These modules are
>   compiled at install time, usually by using Python and node-gyp. One
>   specific limitation of Azure Web Sites is that while it natively
>   understands how to install modules specified in a package.json or
>   npm-shrinkwrap.json file, it does not provide Python or node-gyp and
>   cannot build native modules.
>
> Since Azure Cloud Services rely on the node_modules folder being
>   deployed as part of the application, any native module included as
>   part of the installed modules should work in a cloud service as long
>   as it was installed and compiled on a Windows development system.
>
> Native modules are not supported with Azure Web Sites. Some modules
>   such as JSDOM and MongoDB have optional native dependencies, and will
>   work with applications hosted in Azure Web Sites.

I deployed everything to Azure (using the publishing Wizard) and all the files were sent to Azure (apparently at least), including the compiled modules. When running the site on Azure I obtain the following exception:

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node
```

But that file is in-fact deployed on the server:

[image: files on folder]

Creating a VM would obviously be an option but I would prefer to use web-sites. Anyone has any idea that I can try out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message ""The specified module could not be found" is a bit misleading. It can mean one or more dependent dlls are not found.

I assumed you used the [build instruction](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows) in Windows. If you built canvas against the GTK2 zip file in the instruction, you can copy %GTKDIR%\bin\freetype6.dll to %YourApp%\node_modules\canvas\build\Release. This dll is not copied during the build process. You would need to do this deploying to a VM as well. Or you can build canvas against the [Windows GTK3 bundle](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php).

And unfortunately even after you have all the dll, the sandbox of Azure Websites seems to prevent canvas from running. Hopefully it would be enabled in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the info. After copying "freetype6.dll" the site no longer throws an error but I just get an empty image. I'm going to accept your answer as this does seem an impossible endeavour...

Answer (score 2):

Alright got this working today!

You need to deploy your `node_modules` directory, in addition to that you need to copy all the contents `gtk/bin` to the root of your application, which makes it a bit messy, but it works. I imagine you could change the path to look elsewhere but I needed to get the app running so I didn't investigate any further.

Answer (score 0):

That last line in @mtian's answser is key.  You can spend time getting it to deploy but ultimately the Azure Website VMs lack the GDI+ APIs that node-canvas relies on to execute (presumably blocked for security considerations).  If you want node-canvas on Azure, you can't use Azure Websites and will instead need to setup and manage your own VMs.

Comment: Actually GDI+ seems to work on Azure websites. I've got a demo WebAPI that's using GDI+ to generate map tile images: http://tile-1.azurewebsites.net/tile/10/490/391.png